# Time dilation plus time bandits 2017. Why does my time jump?

Tags: xubuntu, python3

I have a program going through a test. In the program I have a logging function that prints the time the program was run into a log file.

The problem is the time stamps in the log file are jumping around. Below are the actual appended times the program was run and as you can see the time jumps backwards and forwards just as if my Linux distribution was hijacked.

```
    log = open('log.txt', 'a')
    log.write(time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%S')+'\n')
log.close()
2017-05-25 09:00
2017-05-25 09:44
2017-05-25 10:13
2017-05-25 10:30
2017-05-25 10:37
2017-05-25 10:42
2017-05-25 10:39
2017-05-25 10:05
2017-05-25 10:57
2017-05-25 10:36
2017-05-25 10:24
2017-05-25 10:49
2017-05-25 10:15
2017-05-25 10:50
2017-05-25 10:54
2017-05-25 10:50
2017-05-25 10:41
2017-05-25 10:33
2017-05-25 10:37
```

What can be wrong here?

Comment: Does the timestamp get created when the program starts, but not print to the log until execution is completed perhaps?

Comment: The timestamp is the first thing that is done in the program.

Comment: Looks like some iterations of the script take (much) longer to complete than others. Have the test print the start time *and* the finish time to check that possibility.

Comment: The time stamp is first written then the test starts. I wrote the time stamp thing just to know if the program had started running at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A small detail caused the problem.

If you look at the time part it says %H:%S instead of %H:%M which means it counts seconds not minutes. That is why it was moving all over the place.

It is fixed now, thankfully.

Comment: Thread on hold. The question was not about Ubuntu as I first thought. It was about a programming error.